# Creating a queue from timestamps SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, rank

Hello I have a problem trying to create a view symbolizing a queue. It's about students in a waitinglist trying to register for courses. I have a table "Waits" with the attributes queue# TIMESTAMP, stundentID STRING, courseCode STRING,

From this I am trying to create a View which symbolize a queue. lets call it "Queue" with the attributes courseCode STRING, studentID STRING, queue# INT.

queue# in this case will be a number symbolizing the position of your placement in the queue so the older the timestamp is for each student the lower the queue# will be in the view.

I have an idea about how to do this but I don't know how to write it down in code.

```
CREATE VIEW Queue
SELECT code, cid,
CASE 
WHEN MIN(queue#) THEN NVL(MIN(place)) + 1
END AS place; 
FROM Waits
```

If someone could tell me a correct way to formulate my idea to code I would be grateful.

Comment: Seems like a simple use case of `ANALYTIC` function. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to **assign rank** based on the **order of the timestamp**. The older the timestamp, the higher is the rank in the **queue**.

I would suggest **ANALYTIC** function. To keep it simple, you could use `ROW_NUMBER`.

For example,

```
SELECT code, cid, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY timestamp_column) rn
  FROM waits
```

Also, depending on the requirement and complication of the rank, you could also have a look at functions `RANK` and `DENSE_RANK`.

Tim Hall has some very good examples in his article, have a look http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/analytic-functions.php